# Kafka Static IP and Service Discovery

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, service-discovery

I have a three node Kakfa cluster that also has a three node Zookeeper ensemble managing it. My configuration for this cluster looks like

- Node 1

  - IP - 192.168.1.11
  - Kafka Port - 9092
  - Zookeeper Port - 2181
- Node 2

  - IP - 192.168.1.12
  - Kafka Port - 9092
  - Zookeeper Port - 2181
- Node 3

  - IP - 192.168.1.13
  - Kafka Port - 9092
  - Zookeeper Port - 2181

For each of these nodes I have both the Zookeeper and Kakfa configuration files. My sample Zookeeper config file looks like

```
# Zookeeper server config

dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2

server.1=192.168.1.11:2889:3889
server.2=192.168.1.12:2889:3889
server.3=192.168.1.13:2889:3889
```

since each Zookeeper instance needs to know about each other Zookeeper instance and generally from what I have seen, even when managing massive Kafka clusters, there is usually less than 10 Zookeeper nodes. So here we would only need to keep track of 10 IPs. Also from my understanding, these IPs are not as volatile and usually do not change often if ever.

For my Kafka configuration file I have the following on each node

```
# Kafka server properties file

broker.id=<ID for this node>
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
zookeeper.connect=192.168.1.11:2181,192.168.1.12:2181,192.168.1.13:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=36000
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<IP of this node>:9092
```

Now it makes sense to me that each Kafka node we introduce into our cluster has to be aware of all the Zookeeper nodes so it can be managed. But the issue for me is that as we scale the Kafka nodes up or down, we are less certain about their IPs. For example, if I wanted to create a new Kafka topic, I would use the `kafka-topics.sh` shell file that they provide and type something like

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --topic MyTopic --bootstrap-server <IP of one of the Kafka nodes>

# Could also use the broker-list option instead of bootstrap-server to allow multiple IPs
```

The problem for me is, we never know which Kafka IPs are up and running, so passing the IPs to `--bootstrap-server` seems like a guessing game, or I need to manually check a working node for its IP.

So for Kafka, how do I configure a static IP (maybe virtual IP?) so that other services that use my Kafka cluster can always connect to it? How do I perform service discovery for a cluster with changing IPs?

Answer (score 1):

> there is usually less than 10 Zookeeper nodes

According to Kafka Definitely Guide, 7 is generally the max size of a Zookeeper cluster for large Kafka clusters. Personally, I've not seen more than 5 on a Kafka cluster serving millions of events a day...

---

You could make a DNS record that resolves to the healthy instances

However, if IPs aren't static, then clients, in general, would have issues because partition leaders are hosted by IP and broker ID. If an ID moves to a new IP or an IP no longer resolves to a (healthy) Kafka broker, your clients start experiencing errors

Note: both bootstrap-server and broker-list accept multiple addresses, but only the console producer uses broker-list param

There are also other ways to create topics, such as Terraform where you could statically store the Kafka addresses as a variable in source code and rarely ever change it. In particular, you don't need to list every IP each time you use a Kafka client, only a handful

Comment: Does this mean I would need to edit the DNS record of every node each time I add a new broker? What if I had 100 nodes and I added another one to the mix?

Comment: Depends on your infrastructure management scripts. For example, adding an EC2 instance to a VPC service, which is linked to Route53 DNS entry... Otherwise, your router's DNS server would default to use the hostname of the machine, which you'd setup on any new server anyway